# Setting correct permissions automatically for certain file type when file is copied from non-Linux file system

Tags: permissions, chmod, ntfs, file-transfer, umask

The main reason I want this is my heavy use of `dircolors`, especially for `ls --color=auto`.
For example, whenever a `.mp3` file is copied from NTFS, it will have permissions set by `umask 022` which ought to be standard value in most modern distros.
However, for audio files this makes no sense: due to the fact that their permissions get set to `755` (`rwxr-xr-x`), they will get the same color as an **executable shell script**, while I'd really like to have this color reserved for true executables. This is *not* Windows; even *with* the `x` permission set for owner/group/other you cannot expect `./track1.mp3` to work in terminal so that it make an attempt to pick a default console player.

So I'd like to have a certain `umask` ONLY for **audio** files, i. e. that any files like .mp3, .wav, .ogg and so on would always get set their mode to `644`, while leaving all other files copied to this place at their default `umask` of `022`.

Is there any way to accomplish this?
*(NOTE: `cp --preserve` will NOT preserve original permissions on NTFS either, since NTFS is notoriously ignorant about *NIX permission systematic.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the install tool to copy from NTFS.

```
install -m644 file1 ... fileN destination_directory
```

Comment: This is fantastic! First time I've heard of this handy little program. Thank you so much, your answer is _about_ to get my "accepted answer" vote, unless...wait and see.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a script for your own user-defined `cp` command that checks file extensions and uses `chmod` appropriately...

You could do something simple like: (using install rather than cp chmod as per @fd0. That's smarter anyway.)

```
#!/bin/bash

args=("$@")
dest="${args[@]:(-1)}"
unset args[${#args[@]}-1]

if [ ! -d "$dest" ]; then
    echo "Please specify a destination directory as the final argument."
    exit 1
fi

for file in "${args[@]}"; do
    if [ "$file" == *".mp3" ] || [ "$file" == *".wav" ] || [ "$file" == *".ogg" ];  then
        install -m644 "$file" "$dest"
    else
        install -m755 "$file" "$dest"
    fi
done

exit 0
```

Comment: Yeah, it would be nice to have a built-in solution since this type of behavior would make a lot of people happy but I think you may be stuck with a home-grown solution.

Comment: _"since this type of behavior would make a lot of people happy"_ - You can say that again. It's no real fun always having to _remove_ silly permission flags that do not belong there for audio files (e. g. executable in a standalone way).

Comment: All in all this is a nice approach, thank you. I think I can inject some more tricks into my script later myself, e. g. checking out the FROM file system whether it is NTFS, e. g. `result=$(lsblk -no FSTYPE)` and then `test` the `$result` value whether it reads "ntfs". __Caveat:__ _Some big HDDs might consist of partitions with both `ext` and `NTFS` file systems on them, so make sure your arguments for `lsblk` are __partitions__, not devices._